# How can render JSX elements with conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to render html elements if the data is loaded.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    { this.state.isLoaded ?
     (
        <ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />
        <div className="clear" />
        <div className="section-title"></div>
        <ReviewList reviews={this.state.reviews} />
     )
   }
  </div>
);
```

But this shows an error as below.

> SyntaxError: this is a reserved word (60:35)

The 60th line is

```
<ReviewShortIntro review={{this.state.mainReview}} />
```

Without conditional flag (in the code, this.state.isLoaded), i have to check all properties of review is undefined or not.

I am not familiar with react.

What is my best way for resolve problem?

Comment: Can you put your codes on codesandbox?

Comment: Do i put the whole code in the codesandbox?

Comment: yes, I want to check that.

Comment: I think that you should write <ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary operator is incomplete, you only have the left side. You're missing the `: null` part.

You need to wrap multiple elements in a parent element so that you only return a single element. For example, wrapped in a `<div>`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    { this.state.isLoaded ?
     (
        <div><ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />
        <div className="clear" />
        <div className="section-title"></div>
        <ReviewList reviews={this.state.reviews} /></div>
     ) : null
   }
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) use the `&&` operator and you should wrap it in a single element. I recommend to use `Fragment` which do not generate unnecessary dom elements:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    {this.state.isLoaded && (
       <Fragment>
         <ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />
         <div className="clear" />
         <div className="section-title"></div>
         <ReviewList reviews={this.state.reviews} />
       </Fragment>
     )
   }
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<ReviewShortIntro review={{this.state.mainReview}} />
```

With this:

```
<ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />
```

However, I couldn't see using `{{}}` inside the post, but just seeing in your error message. Thus, you need to confirm you're using `this.state.mainReview` inside single curly brace.

The double curly brace means you're defining an object. And object has `key:value` pair. So, using `{{this.state.mainReview}}` will cause you such error as there's no such `key:value` pair.

Though, it might be a typo rather in your code. Just answered to inform that calling a function or whatever the state should be wrapped inside a single curly brace.

---

Ah and yes, your ternary operator is incomplete. Use && operator or complete the ternary operator:

```
{ this.state.isLoaded ?
     (
        <ReviewShortIntro review={this.state.mainReview} />
        <div className="clear" />
        <div className="section-title"></div>
        <ReviewList reviews={this.state.reviews} />
     ) : ''
   }
```